# ICU MessageFormat handle select with blank argument

Tags: php, translation, icu

I want to translate a text using [ICU MessageFormat handling complex arguments](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) but I do not find a way to add a select entry for an empty string / null argument:

```html
{variable, select,
  empty {The translation when variable is null / blank} 
  other {The translation when variable is not null}
}
```

I want to display the `empty` translation when given `variable` is an empty value but I am not able to find the correct syntax to do this.

This returns a syntax error:

```html
{variable, select,
  '' {The translation when variable is null / blank} 
  other {The translation when variable is not null}
}
```

I am using ICU MessageFormat with PHP.

Answer (score 3):

I don't find a way to use empty string reference in ICU message. I would do this way:

```
$variable = "foobar";
echo msgfmt_format_message("en_US", "{variable, select,
    empty {The translation when variable is null / blank} 
    other {The translation when variable is not null}
}", ["variable" => empty($variable) ? "empty" : "other"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution is to use the `variable` itself :

```
{variable, select,
  variable {The translation when variable is null / blank} 
  other {The translation when variable is not null}
}
```

Hope this will help 4 years later :)